# Fuzzy search Shell command?

Tags: bash, terminal, osx-yosemite

The following situation:
I am on a different mac (no command history) using the Terminal (bash) remembering only a part of a command e.g. searching for a command with *util* in it. Did not remember that it was *mdutil*.

**How to fuzzy search for a command in an efficient manner completely in the terminal, without creating new files?**

---

Typical ways I do it now:

To find that command I could google, not always efficient and needs internet connection and browser.

Or <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>, see all commands and scroll through them until I recognize the right one.

Or output all commands to a textfile and search in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
compgen -ca | grep util
```

did it the best. Instead of `util` you can search any part of a command.

Like **gniourf_gniourf** said, a better solution would be

```
compgen -caX '!*util*'
```

Comment: This is a bit ugly... why not `compgen -caX '!*util'` instead?

Comment: Because you are just showing commands ending on `util` that is not fuzzy.

Comment: Sigh. This is a bit ugly... why not `compgen -caX '!*util*'` instead?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could do something like this:

```
oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS=:
for dir in $PATH; do
    ls $dir/*util* 2> /dev/null
done
IFS="$oldIFS"
```

That would loop through all the directories in your `$PATH` looking for a command that contains `util`.

Answer (score 1):

How about starting with `man -k` and refining, like this:

```
man -k util | grep -i meta
Moose::Util::MetaRole(3pm) - Apply roles to any metaclass, as well as the object base class
mdutil(1)                - manage the metadata stores used by Spotlight
```

Comment: Almost. `man -k` is the same as `apropos`. But it shows me also lines where `util` is also in the `whatis` description. It should only show lines where util is before the minus.

Comment: Yep did it with Regex: `apropos util | grep "util[^-\n]* - "`

Comment: @ViktorLexington `apropos -s1` and `apropos -s8` (for sysadmin tools) eliminate a lot of the undesired manpages. (You can combine with  `-s1,8`)